# How can I use the Vim LaTeX-Suite multiple compile option with BibTeX and the -aux-directory option?

Tags: bibtex, compiling, auxiliary-files, vim, vim-latex

I have a document composed of several subfiles and so have used the `-aux-directory` command to put all of the temporary files in a subfolder, 'auxdir', to keep my working folder clear (and me sane).

I now, however, can't use the multiple compile feature of Vim LaTeX-Suite, presumably because the algorithm it follows [(here)](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/compiling-multiple.html) will only run BibTeX if it finds a `\bibdata` line in the aux file, which it can't seem to do if the aux file isn't in the same directory.

The result is that the bibliography isn't compiled at all unless I turn off the `-aux-directory` option, or unless I manually run BibTeX on the aux file. I'm hoping there's a simpler way someone could point out to me!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: You should probably switch to a different compilation mechanism, as vim-latex is not well suited for compiling multiple files.

Comment: @simick: I want to suggest the alternative compilation tool `arara`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Perhaps you might answer, saying that `vim-latex` is not the best tool here?

Answer (score 2):

There are several tools which can can help you.

**`arara`**

The cool tool `arara` provides several rules to specify all compilation steps from inside the document.

For example you want to compile with `pdflatex`+`bibtex`+`pdflatex` you need the following lines in the preamble of the main document:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
```

After this specifications you can compile your document with

```
arara myfile.tex
```

Options to the rules can be given too.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { options: { -aux-directory=auxdir }  }
% arara: bibtex: { files: [auxdir/filename1, auxdir/filename2] }
```

---

**`TrY`**

Another but equal method is the tool TrY. It works only for Unix systems and instead of rules you can type complete small scripts.

The adapted example from above with TrY is:

```
%$ pdflatex myfile.tex
%$ bibtex myfile.aux
%$ pdflatex myfile.tex
```

and the compilation step is:

```
try myfile.tex
```

Comment: Hm... AFAIU the intend of the OP is to use the `-aux-directory=auxdir` option, which puts  all output files but the PDF into `auxdir`. (This option is, unfortunately, only available for MikTex, but pretty similar to `-output-directory`, which is available on all platforms.) Maybe you can extend your example for that case? I guess, the major issue is how the various tools find their intermediate files (now in another directory) and how vim-latex parses the log file and finds the resulting PDF to open the viewer.

Comment: @Daniel: Than TrY is a bad choise ;-). Thanks. But `arara` should work.